# Firestore - why my empty field is not empty?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I stumbled across a very strange error while I was doing my application. There is a function where on button click user can delete the whole Firestore documents AND the corresponding file from Storage. I store the whole URL for the picture in a string field inside the documents - but this url can be empty and this is my problem. I check if this URL field is null but somehow my code manages to skip this logical statement and tries to delete the file and that's where I get a nice nullpointer exception.

```
docRef = fStore.collection("ActiveJobs").document(docID);
    docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                if (documentSnapshot.getString("jobPictureUrl") != null || documentSnapshot.get("jobPictureUrl) != null) {
                    String pictureUrl = documentSnapshot.getString("jobPictureUrl");
                    storageRef = fStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(pictureUrl);
                    storageRef.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

As you can see I do check if this field is empty or not in two different ways but somehow this statement always returns that it's not empty and my storageRef line gets a nullpointer exception, because the pictureUrl above IS empty. I tried to check if pictureUrl is empty, but still got the same error...

[This is how I store the empty string field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqxyF.png)

Hope you can help me out and thanks for reading this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jobPictureUrl` field is not a null member. It's an empty `String`.

So, you have to check whether the `String` is empty; but currently you are doing `null` check.

```java
if (!documentSnapshot.getString("jobPictureUrl").isEmpty()) {
}
```

isEmpty() - Returns `true` if, and only if, string `length()` is 0